# What's wrong with this conditional?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I am trying to make a method that tests to see if 3 lengths can make a triangle. I think i'm making some kind of syntax error but i can't figure out what it is.

Here is the relevant bit of code: (its in java)

```
public static void trya (int a, int b, int c)
{
    if (c>(a+b))
    {
        System.out.println ("yes") ;
    }
    else
    {
        if (b>(a+c)) 
        {
            System.out.println ("yes") ;
        }
    }
    else 
    { 
        if (a>(b+c))
        {
            System.out.println ("yes") ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("no") ;
    }

}
```

this is the error message i get:

```
tryangle.java:17: 'else' without 'if'
        else 
                ^
```

Comment: And what is the error message telling you?

Comment: It would be useful to provide us with whatever errors you're seeing, or an indication of *why* you think you're making a syntax error

Comment: What error do you get? Besides that, an improvement would be to write `else if (condition) {}` instead of `else { if (condition) {} }`. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: The responses `"yes"` and `"no"` are swapped. The triplet `[a=1 b=2 c=5]` *cannot* make a triangle.

Comment: @kenny, your right. i was wondering why it wasn't working right. thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two `else` blocks for the first `if`. Try using `else if`:

```
public static void trya (int a, int b, int c)
{
    if (c>(a+b))
    {
        System.out.println ("yes") ;
    }
    else if (b>(a+c)) 
    {
        System.out.println ("yes") ;
    }
    else if (a>(b+c))
    {
        System.out.println ("yes") ;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("no") ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually there are **three** `else` blocks ;)

Answer (score 11):

As you're a student, I think it's probably appropriate that I point you to the [Control Flow Statements](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html) part of the Java online documentation.

Answer (score 4):

This is invalid:

```
if (cond A) {
    // ...
} else {
    if (cond B) {
        // ...
    }
} else {
    if (cond C) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It should rather be:

```
if (cond A) {
    // ...
} else if (cond B) {
    // ...
} else if (cond C) {
    // ...
}
```

Learn more at [this Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I don't like `if/else` very much.

```
public static boolean isValidTriangle(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return (c > a + b) || (b > a + c) || (a > b + c);
}

public static void trya(int a, int b, int c)
{
    System.out.println(isValidTriangle(a, b, c) ? "yes" : "no");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
public static void trya (int a, int b, int c) 
{ 
    if (c>(a+b)) 
    { 
        System.out.println ("yes") ; 
    } 
    else if (b>(a+c))  
    { 
        System.out.println ("yes") ; 
    } 
    else  if (a>(b+c)) 
    { 
        System.out.println ("yes") ; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        System.out.println ("no") ; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how your code is formatted:

```
if (...) {...}
else {...}
else {...} //else than what?
```

Comment: if the condition (...) is true, the if block will be executed. if the condition is false, the else block will be executed. you have one condition and three else blocks. which one is going to be executed if the condition is false?

Answer (score 1):

It may also be worth pointing out that your method doesn't actually test to see if three lengths can make a triangle. For example, `trya(1, 1, 4)` will result in printing `yes` even though the side lengths 1, 1, 4 do not form a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two `else`s for the same if.  Change your nesting so that you use `else if` rather than

```
else
{
    if
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is you have multiple else blocks, one if statement can have only one else block.